# Python Generator Function Names -- is a prefix helpful?

Tags: python, functional-programming, generator, hungarian-notation

Most functions are easy to name.  Generally, a function name is based on what it does or the type of result it produces.

In the case of a generator function, however, the result could be a iterable over some other type.

```
def sometype( iterable ):
    for x in iterable:
        yield some_transformation( x )
```

The `sometype` name feels misleading, since the function doesn't return an object of the named type.  It's really an iterable over `sometype`.

A name like `iter_sometype` or `gen_sometype` feels a bit too much like [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).  However, it also seems to clarify the intent of the function.

Going further, there are a number of more specialized cases, where a prefix might be helpful.
These are typical examples, some of which are available in [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html).  However, we often have to write a version that's got some algorithmic complexity that makes it
similar to `itertools`, but not a perfect fit.

```
def reduce_sometype( iterable ):
    summary = sometype()
    for x in iterable:
         if some_rule(x): 
             yield summary
             summary= sometype()
         summary.update( x )

 def map_sometype( iterable ):
     for x in iterable:
         yield some_complex_mapping( x )

 def filter_sometype( iterable ):
     for x in iterable:
         if some_complex_rule(x):
              yield x
```

Does the `iter_`, `map_`, `reduce_`, `filter_` prefix help clarify the name of a generator function?  Or is it just visual clutter?

If a prefix is helpful, what prefix suggestions do you have?

Alternatively, if a suffix is helpful, what suffix suggestions do you have?

Comment: I think you kind of over generalized .. i mean, most would simply write your 2nd and 3rd functions directly as generator expressions ala `(some_mapping(x) for x in iterable)`. The first one doesn't really `reduce` anything, its more like a mapping since there is a new `sometype` for each `x`.

Comment: @THC4k: Please imagine that they are more complex.  Too complex to fit easily within `itertools`.  Not so complex that they violate basic functional programming principles.  For example, they might involve a lot of preliminary setup work as an optimization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python `dicts` have `iter*` methods. And lxml trees also have an `iter` method.
Reading

```
for node in doc.iter():
```

seems familiar, so
following that pattern, I'd consider naming the a generator of sometypes `sometypes_iter`
so that I could write analgously,

```
for item in sometypes_iter():
```

Python provides a `sorted` function.
Following that pattern, I might make the verb-functions past tense:

```
sometypes_reduced
sometypes_mapped
sometypes_filtered
```

If you have enough of these functions, it might make sense to make a `SomeTypes` class so the method names could be shortened to `reduce`, `map`, and `filter`.

If the functions can be generalized to accept or return types other than `sometype`, then of course it would make sense to remove `sometype` from the function name, and instead choose a name that emphasizes what it does rather than the types.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that in Python 3, all the dictionary `iter*` methods were removed. For example `iteriterms()` is gone, and the class' `items()` method now does what it did — perhaps indicating that using a prefix isn't considered "Pythonic" by the core language developers — or maybe it was done like that in an effort to make existing code do things in iterable ways by default.